# Nested for and nested if

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to implement a nested for and a nested if statement together. I have the following column below. It needs to look at the column if the range is between 500-1000 it should give recommendation a (i.e. write the recommendation in another column) if it is more than 1000 it should give another recommendation in the responding column.

```
Income Recommendation
550        a
1200       b
750        a
1400       b
600        a
```

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


    For i = 2 To Range(i, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        If Cells(i, 1).Value > 1000 Then

        Cells(i, 10).Value = "b"

        i = i + 1

        Else
            If Cells(i, 1).Value < 1000 Then
                If Cells(i, 1).Valie > 500 Then
                Cells(i, 10).Value = "a"
                End If
                End If
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


    For i = 2 To Range(i, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    
        If Cells(i, 1).Value > 1000 Then
        
        Cells(i, 10).Value = "b"
        
        i = i + 1
        
        Else
            If Cells(i, 1).Value < 1000 Then
                If Cells(i, 1).Valie > 500 Then
                Cells(i, 10).Value = "a"
                End If
                End If
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Comment: Apologies forgot to post my code

Comment: Simple Vlookup() with approximate match will do it for you. Or Lookup() function by keeping data in ascending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this with `Select Case`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 2 To .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row    
            Select Case True    
                Case .Cells(i, 1) > 1000
                    .Cells(i, 10) = "b"    
                Case .Cells(i, 1) < 1000 And .Cells(i, 1) > 500
                    .Cells(i, 10).value = "a"    
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

It is more visible and a bit more understandable. Also, make sure that you refer to the Worksheet (in this case `with ActiveSheet`), to avoid reference problems in the future.

Comment: Even though we assign an initial value of 2 to i. It starts with i=0. Why would that be?

Comment: @YowE3K - I also dislike `Case True` but this seems to be the only way to put an `AND` condition in this case.

Comment: I would have just used `Case > 1000` (to pick up the highest band), then `Case > 500` (to pick up the next band), then `Case Else` (to pick up the leftovers).  It only processes the first one that evaluates to `True` so that layout is equivalent to the `If`/`ElseIf`/`Else` statement I put into my answer.

Comment: @YowE3K - true, but if the requirements change and the OP needs two conditions in the Select Case, it is useful.

Comment: Yes - that is where a `Case True` really is useful - when it isn't a simple "if value is ..." situation.

Comment: Now ... should I be pedantic and say that your `< 1000` should be `<= 1000`  (Nah, I won't mention that! :D)

Answer (score 4):

Several errors:

1. Don't rely on `i` having a value while it is setting the start and end values of the `For` loop - there is a good chance that it is `0` while calculating `Range(i, 1)`.  (Edit: Tested and confirmed that it is still `0` at the point when the end value is being calculated.)  Using `Range(0, 1)` will give a 1004 error.
2. Don't increment the loop counter within the loop (i.e. don't do `i = i + 1`) - it will almost certainly confuse things.  If you really only want to process every second row, use `Step 2` on the `For` statement.
3. `.Valie` should be `.Value`
4. Don't use `Integer` data types for rows - these days Excel can handle 1048576 rows, which is more than an `Integer` can cope with.
5. `Range(1, 1)` is invalid syntax.  When passing two parameters to the `Range` property, they need to be cell references.  Passing a row and column is what is used when using the **`Cells`** property.  (So `Range(1, 1)` will need to be `Cells(1, 1)`, or `Range("A1")`.)

Refactoring your code would give:

```
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row

        If Cells(i, "A").Value > 1000 Then
            Cells(i, "J").Value = "b"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "A").Value > 500 Then
            Cells(i, "J").Value = "a"
        Else
            Cells(i, "J").Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```